# If you need a DBA (doing business as) if your company is legally named "Foo Bar Inc" but you want to be branded as "Foo"

Tags: business

Say you have a company legally named one of these:

- Acme Investments Inc.
- Acme Working Group Inc.
- Acme Bank Inc.
- Acme Technologies Inc.
- Acme Company Inc.
- Acme Inc.

In all these cases, you just want to brand yourself as "Acme", rather than having to put the whole name like "Acme Working Group Inc.". In the case of "Acme Inc.", this seems similar to Google Inc., and we just think of them as "Google" rather than "Google Inc.". I'm wondering if Google in this case has a DBA to go from Google Inc. to Google. Same with Walmart, etc. Or if you can simply brand yourself as Google instead of Google Inc. without a DBA.

In the case where you have something more than just "Foo Inc.", such as "Foo Bar Inc.", wondering if you can also just leave off the "Bar Inc.", so like "Acme Working Group Inc." becomes branded as just "Acme", or if you need to apply for a DBA in this case.

Comment: I think you may be mixing up company names and trademarks. A DBA would be needed if somebody were to write a check to "Foo" when the company name was really "FooBar LLC". DBA is mostly for bank/legal records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better practice would be to get the DBA and/or a trademark of the name. Of course, if someone already has a company called "Foo" this shortening could be problematic in official contexts.